# Could the OSMBonusPack work on an Open Sea Map-project?

Tags: osmdroid, openseamap

I am working on a project where I'm using Open Sea Map, so for this project, I'm only interested in the sea.

I was looking at the features from the OSMBonusPack and I was wondering if it is possible to use those classes on an Open Sea Map? Like route display (that shows proper routes on sea, and doesn't show routes across land), showing Wikipedia POIs related to the current map view etc. The most important thing is the route display, though.

Does anybody have experience with creating such a project?